# MySQL, JSON, Python, Django - error totally whack

Tags: python, mysql, json, django, django-models

I'm trying to populate JSON data fields in a MySQL database from python. I'm using MySQL 5.7.17 which supports the JSON datatype and Python 2.7.  I have defined 6 columns in my table as JSON. One of these fields gets populated from an Insert statement, successfully. I attempt to populate the remaining JSON fields using an UPDATE statement which fails:

> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 202, in execute
>       raise errorclass, errorvalue
>       self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
>   InterfaceError: (-1, 'error totally whack')
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
>       raise errorclass, errorvalue
>   InterfaceError: (-1, 'error totally whack')

In all cases the data is defined as a dictionary in my python code which I then convert to a string like so:

```
my_dict = populate_dictionary() 
my_dict_as_string = json.dumps(my_dict)
```

Has anyone else encountered this?  Perhaps a bug when updating MySQL? I don't have all my data available at the time of the insert otherwise I'd try an insert with all the JSON data.  I also prefer not to defer the insert until I have all the data.

If I store the data as LONGBLOB instead everything works fine but then my Django front end can't read the data.  My Django data model defines all six of these fields as `models.BinaryField()`

Comment: Might be a good idea to output the generated query and provide that for debugging? This (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41868744/updating-mysql-json-field) may be pertinent though?

Comment: I saw that post, but they're using a different mysql python library than I am.  I'm using mysql-python v1.2.4b4.  I just got the same error when replacing my update with an insert into a new test table.  Maybe its my data?  I'll investigate further. Thanks.

Comment: It was a data issue.  There were newline characters in my JSON string.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue trying to populate a MySQL table from Python 2.7 and sqlalchemy but I was able to solve it by creating a **primary key** in the table you are going to append data to.
Try to add another column ID in your MySQL table and from Python create a sequence of unique integers filling that ID column. Finally, append your JSON data as well as ID to MySQL.
In my case, after creating a primary key I didn't encounter any other *error totally whack*

Comment: Thanks.  It was a data issue. There were newline characters in my JSON string.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue but I solved checking better the JSON I was saving, I found that it was malformed and some parts were in "python dictionary" rather than real JSON. I fixed it converting the "python" parts in correct JSON strings.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding another datapoint here.

I hit this `_mysql_exceptions.InterfaceError: (-1, 'error totally whack')` error with an old python 2.7 script (I know, I know, don't hate me but if ain't broke, etc).

The script was performing a `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` on a 5.7 server and this broke when the server was upgraded to 8.0

It turns out that the default setting on 5.7 is `local_infile = ON` but in 8.0 it is (quite sensibly) set to `local_infile = OFF` This can be altered dynamically (no need to restart mysqld, but remember to update the conf) and resolves the issue.

So the script lives to see another day...

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar issue which was due to some null data insertion fixed it by checking the valid JSON content before dump and insert into DB